# Personal Message History In-Game

Tags: league-of-legends

When holding an extended conversation with someone, sometimes it is desirable to multitask and get some games in. Unfortunately, the loading screen for the game doesn't display messages, and so messages received while the game is loading seem to be inaccessible until you leave the game, where you can see the full history again.

Other than using an external chat system, or asking people to resend messages once you enter the game proper, both of which require extra effort on their part, is there a way to continue these conversations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually possible to access the main window and see your full chat history (since you logged in, anyway).

[image]

Once the AIR client closes down and you begin to load, go into your tray and find the Riot Games icon. (In the image above, it's the leftmost icon.) Click it and the AIR client will come back, allowing you to interact as usual and scroll up as well.

This has a downside though: whenever you get messaged, the AIR client will flash on the toolbar, which can be distracting. (Obviously, this does not apply in fullscreen.) In addition, you'll hear the new message sound. You can mitigate the former by minimising the AIR client to tray if you don't need it through a utility such as [PowerMenu](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-minimize-an-application-to-system-tray-in-windows/).

Comment: Done this quite a few times on accident but never really understood how useful it would be for conversations. +1

Answer (score 3):

Actually, messages that you receive while in the loading screen will be queued and sent to you in the in-game chat once you load.

There currently isn't a way to look at the history of your chat in-game. And the chat window outside of game is only for the most recent session.

Also, when you type /r to reply to people in-game, you're replies aren't logged into the temporary chat history once you leave the game. So the chat window with your friend will only show the conversation you had before the game and everything they have sent you once you entered the game but not the replies messages you sent to them.

Comment: When does that start? I've definitely noticed messages that I didn't see during champ select, or when the game started in the out-of-game chat window.

Comment: @Sconibulus basically when you are in the loading screen when you can't access the chat window.